# What are the advantages of using callbacks over strings to encapsulate code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

In javascript, it's possible to store code as string and execute it with 'eval'. On the other hand, we can represent code as a function for further execution. Why is preferable to use closures over 'eval' in javascript?

**EDIT:**

For example:

Code stored as string:

```
function(x, y, callback){
  if (x > y){
      eval(callback);
  }
}
```

Code stored as function:

```
function(x, y, callback){
  if (x > y){
      callback();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example where `eval` would replace a closure?

Comment: @le_m see my edit.

Comment: There's no closure in that edit.

Comment: Your example is not even closure

Comment: A *closure* is a function with a free variable plus the outer scope where that variable is defined.

Comment: consider callback as the closure..

Comment: so, call it what it is, rather than what it isn't.

Comment: You really should consider `String`s as immutable data in Javascript, not as code. `eval` just brings you to the dark side.

Comment: How come this question get upvotes?!?

Comment: @ftor It's a daring question confronting us with our worst fears. Such boldness deserves an upvote.

Comment: @ftor Do you mean that eval should never be used?

Comment: @le_m haha, agreed!

Comment: @Eduardo I think Javascript doesn't suffer from too little dynamic features, but from to many. So yes, I wouldn't use it. But this is my personal opinion.

Comment: Maybe you can answer the question yourself if I ask you: Why did you write your example this way instead of doing `eval("function foo(x, y, callback) { if ( x > y) { callback(); } }"` ? I.e. why are you not using `eval` at the top level and write all your code inside a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` itself does not create a closure and does not provide encapsulation. It is merely a means to evaluate JavaScript code represented as a string.

If you use `eval` to execute a function (like your example does), it will not modify the scope of that function nor the closure created by that function. Regardless of `eval`, functions always execute in the scope in which they were originally declared and they always create a closure (which encapsulates any declarations made within that function).

There's only one minor nuance involving scope and `eval`. If you invoke `eval` directly it will use the local scope. If you invoke `eval` indirectly, it will use the global scope.

Example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
function test() {
  var x = 2, y = 4;
  console.log(eval('x + y'));  // Direct call, uses local scope, result is 6
  var geval = eval; // equivalent to calling eval in the global scope
  console.log(geval('x + y')); // Indirect call, uses global scope, throws ReferenceError because `x` is undefined
}
```

Comment: Also, `eval` can't be optimized and is slow compared to a function call. Also, debugging is more complicated. And IDEs don't check code strings for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a string, you don't remove the closure. The function still has to be in the same scope it would have to be as if you were calling the function directly. Generally you want to avoid using eval as it is slower. For example:

```
function sayHi() {
    alert('hi');

    function sayHo() {
        alert('ho');
    }

    sayHo()
}

function callAnotherFunctionByString(func) {
    eval(func)
}

function callAnotherFunction(func) {
    func()
}

// Both of these will work
callAnotherFunctionByString('sayHi()');
callAnotherFunction(sayHi);

// Neither of these will work because the sayHo function is closed off to the sayHi function
callAnotherFunctionByString('sayHo()');
callAnotherFunction(sayHo);
```